# c# WebApi.SelfHost post is null

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

I am using the [WebApi.SelfHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost/) but my Post is always null.
I tried all the solutions I could find on SO, but none of them worked.

I'm stuck with this problem for hours.
I tried all the solutions I could find on SO but none of them worked.

I know this question is already asked. But I already tried al of the solutions but none of them worked. and they are not using self host.

Here is my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

public class testController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string test(int id ,[FromBody]string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I am using [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for testing

here is my result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have entered string value into headers section of request. You should send that value in body of request. E.g. put header

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

And add body (below headers section, named *raw payload*)

```
"testValue"
```

NOTE: Consider to use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)